# Android Emulator device won't boot

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I am running android studio through the cloud  (Using Paperspace).  When I tried to run an emulator with a HAXM based system, it says it isn't compatible with nested system, however ARM system images are.  But when I try to emulate a nexus with an arm system image, the device won't power on.  It's powered up once, but it was on the android logo for half an hour before I just closed it.  Is there any way to fix either the problem or run it differently through the android studio emulator?